# Not Able to Insert uniqid() value into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I've inserting rows into a database from a test form and when I bring in uniqid(), it doesn't work. The form works fine and inserts the data but when I bring in the unique row it doesn't.

I originally had the 'unique' row in my MySQL database set as VARCHAR(500) and didn't know if that was the problem so I changed it to TEXT(500). It shouldn't be the problem since I've echoed out $unique and it's just numbers and letters but I wasn't sure if the server side script interprets it a certain. I also didn't know what else to do to debug! I've searched around to if there's something special I should do when inserting a uniqid() value into a database but it doesn't seem to be different than any other value. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

```
$test1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['test1']);
$test2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['test2']);
$test3 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['test3']);
$test4 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['test4']);
$unique = uniqid();

//ECHO OUT UNIQUE ID TO MAKE SURE IT WORKED
echo "<script>alert('".$unique."');</script>";

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO users (test1, test2, test3, test4, unique) VALUES ('$test1', '$test2', '$test3', '$test4', '$unique')";
$result_insert = $mysqli->query($sql_insert);

//ECHO OUT UNIQUE ID AGAIN TO MAKE SURE IT REMAINS THE SAME (AND IT DOES)
echo "<script>alert('".$unique."');</script>";

//IF EVERYTHING WORKS, FORWARD TO SECOND FORM PAGE
if($result_insert){
    header('Location:second_form.php');
}
//IF THERE IS AN ERROR INSERTING THE DATA, GIVE AN ERROR MESSAGE
else{
    echo "<script>alert('There was an error submitted your info. Please try again.');</script>";
}
```

### EDIT

Echo'ed $mysqli-error and this is what I got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'unique) VALUES ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4',
>   '51bd57e7bf4dd')' at line 1

I don't see an error in that area of the code?

Comment: have you tried printing the error `$mysqli->error` if any ? does your else error trigger at all ? Also yes `uniqid()` will not change, because you have saved it to the variable `$unique`. It will only change, if you call `uniqid()` again.

Comment: The else error triggers every time. Have not printed mysqli error. Will do that now.

Comment: I'm guessing the column name `unique` is causing an error, try escaping it with `

Comment: @Dale, you may be right. I didn't think about that. I can just rename the column, it's not important that it's named unique. I'll see if that's the case.

Comment: @MxmastaMills also you can put unique back to `varchar`, the max length of `uniqid()` without it set to true is of 13.

Comment: @Dale, that was the case. I guess 'unique' is not a good thing to use for a column name. You can write that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @MxmastaMills he may be right about the column name but despite that using the MySQL error is one way to know what went wrong. `UNIQUE` is a mysql function so to use it as column name you must escape it so it becomes `\`unique\`` on your query

Comment: Prix is right, if ever this happens again you'll be able to fix it yourself using the error :)

Comment: @MxmastaMills the error pinpoint the problem being the `unique` here `right syntax to use near 'unique)`

Comment: @Prix, yeah thanks for that. I'm relatively new to PHP so I'm still learning debugging, that was a totally oversight on my part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIQUE` is a [reserved MySQL word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You should use backticks and that should fix the problem.